# pnpm installations cause pnpm-lock.yaml file to update each time

Tags: javascript, node.js, monorepo, pnpm

I have a pnpm monorepo, and I'm trying to bring my project to a state where my `pnpm install` command doesn't update the lock file. As I understand, for example, after I change some package version in a `package.json` file and run `pnpm install`, a new lock file is generated with the exact version of the package that was installed and its dependencies. After that, when I run `pnpm install` again, there should be no changes in the lock file because all the exact versions in the lock file are aligned with the `package.json` file. But for some reason, subsequent installations cause a lock file update. I tried to remove all the `node_modules` and cache before instalations with a command similar to

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -type d -prune -exec rm -rf '{}' + && rm -rf $(pnpm store path) && pnpm install
```

Other people on different machines also experienced this behavior with this project, but apart from that, I haven't seen pnpm bugs reported about this, which means it may be project-specific. Maybe someone has an idea about what the issue might be.

system: macOS Monterey, Apple M1

node version: 16.13.0

pnpm version: 7.17.1

Comment: Why is generating a new lock file everytime a problem for you?

Comment: If I understand correctly, different lock file means different dependencies (versions) are installed between installations and people, and lock files exist for this specific reason to prevent such differences

Comment: You can try command-line arguments `--frozen-lockfile --no-verify-store-integrity`, which are implied in build pipelines that set the environment variable `CI`.